# How to write a select query to find FIFO deviation

Tags: postgresql

I have table name as products. on that table 4 columns as product_name, created_at, delivery_date, employee_code.
My query is how to retrieve the data where FIFO deviated.

For example first created product delivered by first only.

how to write a select query for above scenario?

Comment: Could you share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71432273/18336514

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem:

```sql
with ps as (
    select *,
       lag(delivery_date, 1) over (order by created_at, delivery_date) as prev_delivery_date
    from products
    order by created_at, delivery_date
)
select *
from ps
where delivery_date < prev_delivery_date;
```

### How it does

In sql, it's general practice to say the exact thing you want (with a little sql terms :) ), since sql is declarative it'll be easy to implement once you have the exact sentence.
We exactly want below:

> Give me all the products that when I sort by order_date, previous row's delivery_date is greater than current rows delivery date. Which means it broke FIFO.

To get previous row, we'll use `lag`, `lag` gives a column of a row that is N before the current row (first row will have empty `lag` value, because there's no previous row). It's a window function, `sum` and `count` are window functions , looking at their input and output may decrypt the window function term if you haven't heard. What `sum` does: it somehow goes through all rows and returns you their total summation. So we can say that window functions, operate over all the table and returns a single result. You can choose the order of the "table" which window function operates, since we want to get previous row in the context of creation date, `order by created_date` is the solution. You say, "follow this pattern for this window function" via `over`. Also keep in mind that window functions do not respect the ordery you give for the "whole query", for the result actually. For example in this query `select SOME_WINDOW_FUNCTION_FOO from foo order by bar`, `order by bar` won't used by window functions even if you say `over ()`.

We can't get window function results in `where`, thus single query is not enough (query like `select * ..... where delivery_date < prev_delivery_date`). You can use a subquery, and use `from` but I find CTE more readable.

`with ps as (....) select ...` part is CTE.
Inside the `ps` CTE, we select all the fields `*` and `lag(delivery_date,1)` this gives the "previous" row of this column.

Later is simple we just get the products that `delivery_date < prev_delivery_date`.

### Test

```sql
create table products (
  product_name text, 
  created_at timestamptz, 
  delivery_date timestamptz, 
  employee_code text
);

insert into products (product_name, created_at, delivery_date, employee_code)
values 
    (
      'p-1', '2024-01-01 12:00:00', '2024-01-02 12:00:00', 'code-1'
    ),
    (
      'p-2', '2024-01-03 12:00:00', '2024-01-04 12:00:00', 'code-2'
    ),
    (
      'p-3', '2024-01-05 12:00:00', '2024-01-06 12:00:00', 'code-3'
    ),
    (
      'p-4', '2024-01-04 12:00:00', '2024-01-08 12:00:00', 'code-4'
    ),
    (
      'p-5', '2024-01-01 06:00:00', '2024-01-01 10:00:00', 'code-5'
    );

-- above select
-- Result:
-- p-3  2024-01-05T12:00:00.000Z    2024-01-06T12:00:00.000Z    code-1  2024-01-08T12:00:00.000Z
```